# número de dias da semana por mês

Tags: php

Preciso verificar o número da semana e contar quantos dias tem cada semana do mês.

Com este código, sei o numero da semana no mês (não a semana do ano):

```
function weekOfMonth($date) {
    // estract date parts
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));

    // current week, min 1
    $w = 1;

    // for each day since the start of the month
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $d; ++$i) {
        // if that day was a sunday and is not the first day of month
        if ($i > 1 && date('w', strtotime("$y-$m-$i")) == 0) {
            // increment current week
            ++$w;
        }
    }

    // now return
    return $w;
}
```

Agora pretendo contar quantos dias tem cada número da semana (Setembro 2017):

```
d  s  t  q  q  s  s
               01 02 = semana 1 -> 2 dias
03 04 05 06 07 08 09 = semana 2 -> 7 dias
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 = semana 3 -> 7 dias
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 = semana 4 -> 7 dias
24 25 26 27 28 29 30 = semana 5 -> 7 dias
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function weekOfMonthWithWeek($date) 
{
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);
    $weeks = array();
    $s = date('w', strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-01"));
    $t = date('t', strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-01"));
    $c = 0;
    $i = 1;
    $weeks['month_year'] = "$y - $m";
    for($ini = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-01"));
        $ini <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-{$t}"));
        $ini = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ini." +1 days")))
    {
        if ($s == 6)
        {
            $s = 0;             
            $weeks['items'][] = array('week' => $i++, 'total_days' => $c+1);    
            $c = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $c++;
            $s++;
        }

    }
    if ($s != 0) $weeks['items'][] = array('week' => $i++, 'total_days' => $c);


    return $weeks;
}


var_dump ( weekOfMonthWithWeek('2017-01-20') );
```

[Exemplo OnLine - Ideone](https://ideone.com/NVpN96)

Comment: Porque votoram negativo, tem algo de errado, que eu possa arrumar? ou está errado?

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra solução é fazer um array baseado no `date('W', ...)` e incrementar ele, por exemplo:

```
function DiasPorSemana($data)
{
    $tempo = strtotime('first day of this month', strtotime($data));
    $limite = date('t', $tempo);
    $resultado = array_fill((int)date('W',$tempo), 6, 0);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $limite; $i++){
        $resultado[(int)date('W', $tempo + (86400 * $i))] += 1; 
    }

    return array_values(array_filter($resultado));
}
```

Usando:

```
var_dump(DiasPorSemana('2017-09-13'));
```

Retornará:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
  [2]=>
  int(7)
  [3]=>
  int(7)
  [4]=>
  int(7)
}
```

---

Primeiro pegamos o primeiro dia do mês, usando:

```
$tempo = strtotime('first day of this month', strtotime($data));
```

Depois pegamos a quantidade de dias que tem neste mês:

```
$limite = date('t', $tempo);
```

Criamos um array com o valor `0` para todos os possíveis semanas. O `date('W',$tempo)` será a primeira semana do ano daquele mês, assim se ele for `10` criaremos uma array contendo de `10` até `15`, todos com o valor inicial de `0`:

```
$resultado = array_fill((int)date('W',$tempo), 6, 0);
```

Fazemos um loop de todos dias possíveis e incrementamos (`+= 1`) na array onde possui a chave/index com o valor igual à respectiva semana, assim permitirá contar o número de dias existentes naquela semana.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $limite; $i++){
    $resultado[(int)date('W', $tempo + (86400 * $i))] += 1; 
}
```

Depois retornarmos os valores, removemos das semanas com `0` dias e também "refazemos" o index da array, partindo de `0`:

```
return array_values(array_filter($resultado));
```